# Display time from database in React Semantic UI with React Moment

Tags: reactjs, datetime, time, momentjs, semantic-ui-react

A timestamp string is stored in database like so:

```
startsAt: 1535705100000
endsAt: 1535708100000
```

currently there is as a `const endTime` that should convert the timestamp string into a human-readable, as well as a TimeInput field like this:

import Moment from "react-moment";
    ..

```
  const endTime = (
    <Moment unix format="HH:mm">
      {endsAt / 1000}
    </Moment>
  );
```

.

```
..
import { TimeInput } from "semantic-ui-calendar-react";

      <TimeInput            
        ..
        name="startsAt"
        placeholder="00:00"
        value={endTime}
        ..
      />
```

With that `const endTime` declared, what is being rendered to the input field is [object Object].

The question is - whether I can use  to create a constant at all to be displayed as a value in the TimeInput component.

OR/ALSO - what is the best way to render a readable time from a string in such scenario? Desired output: H:mm

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your console. My guess is you are probably also getting a prop-type error for the `value` prop on your TimeInput component. It is rendering [object Object] because you are passing a React component there instead of a string. So it looks like `value` does not accept a React component as input.

You are using `react-moment` as your package to convert time. But it is always going to render some sort of html tag around your string when converting the time displayed. You should instead try using `moment` instead. The main library will return you an actual string which you can directly pass to your `value`.

Answer (score 0):

Q: whether I can use to create a constant at all to be displayed as a value in the TimeInput component.

A: Yes you can!

BTW you  have messed up types - this is a cause why your example doesn't work correctly.

Let's look on types:

- `endTime` is described as `const` of type `JSX.Element`
- property `value` of `TimeInput` element has type of `string`

So you are using incompatible types as compatible!

The example of how `Moment`, `moment` and `TimeInput` should be used together:

```
import "./styles.css";
import moment from "moment";
import Moment from "react-moment";
import { TimeInput } from "semantic-ui-calendar-react";

export default function App() {
  const endsAt = 1535708100000;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React-moment usage example</h1>

      <Moment unix format="HH:mm">
        {endsAt / 1000}
      </Moment>

      <TimeInput
        name="startsAt"
        placeholder="00:00"
        value={moment(endsAt).format("HH:mm")}
        onChange={() => {
          return;
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Take a look onto working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-napier-kc6q6k?file=/src/App.tsx